# Apache HTTP forward proxy to multiple destinations

Tags: apache, proxy, http-proxy, mod-proxy

I'm trying to set up an apache HTTP service as a forward proxy that can proxy some requests to another proxy server and other requests directly.  I have a Virtual host configured like

```
<VirtualHost 10.1.1.3:9000>
  ServerName 0.0.0.0
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
  <Directory "/var/www/htm">
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes +FollowSimLinks
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ProxyRequests On
  ProxyVia On
  SSLProxyEngine On
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyTimeout 60
  ProxyRemote "*" "http://otherproxy:8088"
  <ProxyMatch "^https?:\/\/my.*\.internal.*">
    ProxyPass "https://my.website.internal"
  </ProxyMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, whenever I try to route through the proxy I get an HTTP 503 error.  It seems to be selecting the ProxyRemote directive

```
[internal-server]$ https_proxy=http://10.1.1.3:9000 curl -kLv https://my.website.internal
....
Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT
[internal-server]$ https_proxy=http://10.1.1.3:9000 curl -kLv https://github.com
....
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
....
<!doctype html> .....
```

Comment: This is using Apache httpd 2.4.6

Comment: Commenting out `ProxyRemote ... ` command allows the internal connection to webserver to work but prevents public access to github. and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found to do this was by using multiple VirtualHosts and wildcard ServerAlias directives.

```
# Default - Send all request to proxy to outside world
<VirtualHost 10.1.1.3:9000>
  ServerName 0.0.0.0
  ProxyRequests On
  ProxyVia On
  SSLProxyEngine On
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyTimeout 60
  ProxyRemote "*" "http://otherproxy:8088"
</VirtualHost>

# don't proxy specific internal domains
<VirtualHost 10.1.1.3:9000>
  ServerName direct.internal
  ServerAlias *.somedomain.internal
  ServerAlias *.anotherinternal.domain
  ProxyRequests On
  ProxyVia On
  SSLProxyEngine On
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyTimeout 60
</VirtualHost>
```